# How to deploy a middleman blog inside a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleman

I have a rails app. I want to make a blog for it with middleman and in subdirectory. For example www.myapp.com/blog .
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MiddleMan's output is a static HTML/JS/CSS website. Just place the output of your MiddleMan project in the `public/blog` directory within your Rails app.

Comment: Thank you @meagar. You mean I should generate a middleman project inside the public/blog?

Comment: No, your MiddleMan project can reside *anywhere*, and your Rails app can reside *anywhere*. You just need to include the compiled output of your MiddleMan project inside the `public/blog` directory of your deployed Rails app.

Comment: excuse me, but how? Can you explain more ?

Comment: @Ahmad There is no more I can explain in this context without you asking a specific question. You need to go learn how MiddleMan works and how Rails works, and then tell us what part of this is unclear to you.